# LINQ Group By Sum how do i return null for decimal type field

Tags: linq

I am writing LINQ query to **return null** if it does not have any value (null in database) but return **0 or proper number** if it has 0 or proper number in database.

I have following my model class

```
public class Test
{
  public decimal? TotalHours { get; set; }
}
```

The following is LINQ selection query. This line assign null to TotalHours successfully. I am fine till here.

```
List<Test> Item = parentQuery
.Select(x => new Test
{
TotalHours Hours = (decimal?) x.TotalMinutes != null ? (decimal?) x.TotalMinutes : (decimal?)null,
}).ToList();
```

My further group by query assign 0 if TotalHours is null whereas i am expecting it be assigned/remained as null.

```
List<Test> ItemList = Item.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
  .Select(x => new Test
   {
   TotalHours = x.Sum(y => (decimal?)y.TotalHours)
}).ToList();
```

How i can return null to  my view? kindly dont advise Data Annotation way.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be testing for presence of non-`null` values explicitly:

```
List<Test> ItemList = Item.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new Test {
        TotalHours = x.Any(y => y.TotalHours.HasValue) ? x.Sum(y => (decimal?)y.TotalHours) : null
    }
).ToList();
```

The check with `Any(...)` verifies that the group has at least one non-`null` item before using `Sum`. If all items are `null`, the expression produces `null` result.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight , my issue solved with your suggestion.

Comment: You said "One way of doing" which is fine.. What would be the other way? is there any other way you would like mention here please?

Comment: @user1874957 Another one would be splitting the list of groups to a sub-list that has non-null items and another sub-list that does not, using "straight" `Sum` for the first one, and using `null`s for the second one, and finally concatenating the two results in the end. This would eliminate the conditional expression inside `Select`, but the overall logic would become harder to follow.